# Regular expression which matches a specific pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find a regular expression in Perl which matches a pattern such as this:

```
my $sumthing = "people say
for -->";
```

Over here after `say` there is a single newline character. So I need to find a regular expression which could match such a pattern which includes a newline within a pattern. Please help me to find this as I'm new to Perl & regular expression.

The possible methods I tried were these:

```
if (($sumthing !~ (/\n+$/)) && ($sumthing !~ (/^\n+/m)))
```

They kindly help me to find out an expression to match this kind of a pattern, but not getting the output as desired.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want. Do you want match that string exactly? If so, you could use

```
$sumthing =~ /^people say\nfor -->\z/
```

or

```
$sumthing eq "people say\nfor -->"
```

Or maybe what you need to know is that `.` matches any character including newline when `/s` is used?

```
/people .* -->/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`/s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) modifier which causes `.`to match anything, including a newline.

```
my $str = "people say for\nsomething...";
$str =~ m{say(.*)}s and print "'$1'\n";
```

This would print:

```
' for
something...'
```

Comment: This will match string without \n too

Answer (score 0):

The following will check for anything then new line then anything. Not sure if I totally understood your question.

```
if($sumthing =~ m/.*\n.*/)
```

Comment: You can leave out the '.*' parts. They are unnecessary: /\n/. So now, you could also do index($something, "\n") < 0.